# How to get total revenues per customer

Tags: stripe-payments

How to get total revenue per customer in stripe for time period.

Is there any option on stripe, where we can track total revenues per customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to retrieve all Charges and sum it up for a given Customer.